# Having trouble with a very simple datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, datepicker

I have a website where clients need to verify their age before they may continue. I need a basic datepicker that basically works like radio buttons. Group 1 is "day". Images for the numbers 1 to 31 is displayed. Group 2 is "month". Jan to Dec is displayed. Group 3 is "year". 1938 to 1997 is displayed.

As soon as you land on the page, all three groups are immediately displayed. There is no fancy dropdown or annimation. I want it to be as simple as "click click click continue"

I have tried replacing standard radio buttons with images, but that proved to be quite complicated. Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Do you somehow disable February, April, June, September, and November when they pick 31, and disable February when they pick 30?  Do you disable the non-leap-years when they pick 29 and February?

Comment: Yes you can...
You have to nadle it programmatically and have user give inputs in YY MM DD fashin, just to avoid confusion...

Comment: @AdityaParab - Yes, you could.  But when day is listed as Group 1, month as Group 2, and year as Group 3, presumably the idea is to enter them in that order.

Comment: Also, are people older than 74 ineligible?

Comment: Thats fine... Put the groups in order of Group3 3roup2 and Group1... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use datepicker and use onShow and pickerClass to define whatever UI you want there...check this for reference

http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use select tag. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GywwY/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Select would work just fine.

```
Day:
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
.
.
.
.
</select>

Month:
<select>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
.
.
.
.
</select>

Year:
<select>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

OR

You can use jQuery's .datepicker()

You need to include jQuery UI's script for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, but this requires dropdowns and scrolling. Thats not what im looking for